# How can I notify source property about the changes made in Wpf DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid, dependency-properties

I have a Datagrid bound to Datatable through Dependency property. I am unable to retrieve changes I make in datagrid even when I have set binding mode as two way.

What are the best possible ways to update changes back to Source DataTable when dataGrid is edited?

I know I can use DataAdapter.Update() to commit changes to database but that's not what I am asking so don't confuse. I want to know effecient ways to save changes back to ViewModel's DataTable Property.

**The Datatable property is populated at runtime as:**

```
class EmployeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{



    private DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    public DataTable _Table
    {
        get
        {
            return _dt;
        }
        set
        {
            _dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanges(nameof(_Table));
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanges(String propertyName)
    {

        var h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        //   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        
        ReadData();
    }

    

   
    public void ReadData()
    {

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Employee.mdf"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblStudents", con);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(set, "Students");
            _Table = set.Tables[0];

        }
    }
}
```

**The custom usercontrol named StudentsGrid is just a datagrid inside a grid:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ADO.Net_Practice.StudentsGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ADO.Net_Practice"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsTable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:StudentsGrid}}, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="200"/>            
</Grid>
```

**and this is the code-behind of above xaml where dependency property is registered:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StudentsGrid.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StudentsGrid : UserControl
    {
        public StudentsGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public DataTable StudentsTable
        {
            get { return (DataTable)GetValue(StudentsTableProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StudentsTableProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StudentsTable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StudentsTableProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StudentsTable", typeof(DataTable), typeof(StudentsGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new DataTable(), StudentsTablePropertyChanged));

        private bool _updating;

        private static void StudentsTablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var st = d as StudentsGrid;
            if(st!=null)
            {
                st.DataChanged();
            }
        }

        private void DataChanged()
        {
            if (_updating)
                return;
            _updating = true;
            
            _updating = false;
        }
    }
```

**The final is MainWindow which binds the StudentsTable property to the custom user control:**

```
<Grid>
        
        <local:StudentsGrid StudentsTable="{Binding _Table, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

</Grid>
```

**The datacontext of mainWindow is set in code-behind's constructor as:**

```
 DataContext = new EmployeeViewModel();
```

**This is the result I get:**
[image: The Data Grid populated from the database]

Comment: A silly mistake.. i am sorry.. the name of _Table was DataSet earlier.

Comment: Why don't you bind to the `DataView` of the `DataTable`? `set.Tables[0].DefaultView;` The `DataGrid` will modify the object you bind to.

Comment: If your problem is related to a typo and you have already fixed  it, then you should consider to delete your question. It's of no value.

Comment: No its not related to a typo. Typo was made by mistake. The question is "what are the efficient ways to retrieve changes and save changes to datatable property _Table".